# Except exception in IOLoop add_timeout callback function

Tags: python, exception, callback, tornado

So I am scheduling a callback using

`ioloop.IOLoop.instance().add_timeout(time, callback_func)`

But my `callback_func` may throw `Exception` which I want to catch.

Tried whats suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20661979/2341189) but doesn't seem to work. Or maybe I am not doing it the right way. Any help on this would be great.

Code is somewhat like this:

**start.py**

```
class Start:
    # ... other methods ...
    @staticmethod
    def initialize():
        OtherClass.initialize()

def main():
    Start.initialize()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

**other_class.py**

```
class OtherClass:
    @staticmethod
    def initialize():
        ioloop.IOLoop.instance().add_timeout(time, callback_func)

    @staticmethod
    def callback_func():
        # Need to catch any exception which occurs here.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `callback_func` is your own code, then *by far* the simplest way to catch all exceptions there is to simply wrap the whole function body in try / except:

```
@staticmethod
def callback_func():
    try:
        # ... your code ...
    except Exception as exc:
        # handle it
```

It's simple and everyone who reads your code will understand it, no surprises.

If you want to do something exotic and Tornado-specific, use an ExceptionStackContext:

```
from tornado import ioloop
from tornado.stack_context import ExceptionStackContext


class OtherClass:
    @staticmethod
    def initialize():
        ioloop.IOLoop.instance().add_timeout(1, OtherClass.callback_func)

    @staticmethod
    def callback_func():
        # Need to catch any exception which occurs here.
        1 / 0

class Start:
    # ... other methods ...
    @staticmethod
    def initialize():
        with ExceptionStackContext(Start.handler):
            OtherClass.initialize()

    @staticmethod
    def handler(exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback):
        print("Caught %r in Handler" % exc_type)
        return True  # Tell Tornado that we handled it.

def main():
    Start.initialize()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Best of all, use coroutines instead of callbacks. Coroutines are as efficient as callbacks, but give you regular Python exception handling semantics. See my article [Refactoring Tornado Coroutines](http://emptysqua.re/blog/refactoring-tornado-coroutines/) and the [Tornado guide](http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/stable/guide/coroutines.html).

Comment: Yes exception handling can be done in callback function itself, but thats not what I am looking for. Its done this way at so many other places, that I want to put a possible solution in common caller class `Start` so that I dont have to put `try except` for complete callback code or to put your other solution in other files being called from `Start` with similar callback.

Comment: Your solution works well and as expected. Thanks. But could there be more generic solution which can be applied to base `Start` class.

Comment: Edited my answer - I now show how you can move the handler into the Start class and use the ExceptionStackContext from Start.initialize instead of from OtherClass.initialize.